Variational Autoencoders (VAEs) - creating a handcrafted example
In learning about variational autoencoders (VAEs), I would like to come up with a nice little handcrafted example to help make sense of them thoroughly. For this, suppose I know that my samples are drawn from a five-dimensional Gaussian $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,\dots,X_5)$ in which $X_2\sim\mathcal{N}(1,1)$ and $X_5\sim\mathcal{N}(-1,4)$ are independent and $X_1=X_2$, $X_3=X_5$ and $X_4=X_2+X_5$. Suppose further that our soon to be learned VAE has a latent dimension of two. In that case (correct me if I am wrong), I would expect that the latent space $\mathbf{Z}$ is effectively just the two-dimensional Gaussian $(X_2,X_5)$ as all other random variables in the observed data depend entirely on these two and they are independent.
$\textbf{Question(s) (1):}$ Am I correct in thinking that given some sample $\mathbf{x}=(x_2,x_5)$ we would ideally have that $\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{x}$ is just $(x_2,x_5)$ itself? As in, would a well-learned encoder yield something which when sampled from yields samples very close to $(x_2,x_5)$?
I'm unsure as I think that $\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{x}$ should be a distribution and to 'guarantee' the output $(x_2,x_5)$ we would perhaps require something like $p(\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{x})=\delta(z_1-x_2)\delta(z_2-x_5)$ where $\delta$ is the dirac delta function. I'm a bit miffy on the rigorous details here, so help is appreciated.
$\textbf{Question (2):}$ In practice, I understand that $\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{x}$ is approximated by some normal distribution whose parameters are output by some neural network (the encoder). I suppose in this case it'd make sense for a 'good' encoder to output the parameters of a normal distribution whose mean is centred at $(x_2,x_5)$ and covariance matrix is diagonal with relatively small diagonal elements (say $0.01$ or so). Is this intuition correct and in line with what would would expect the learned encoder to do in practice?
